# How ALU execute instruction in AMD GPU (VLIW)?

Tags: opencl, alu, vliw

I wanna ask something about OpenCL programming.
I understand that a quarter of wavefront  can issue instruction for each cycle clock and it will need four cycle clock to call a wavefront. 
To finish the instruction in VLIW architecture, it will need eight cycle clock.
So, calling another wavefront is a solution. If I call two wavefront then 
it will be eight cycle clocks. So after wavefront A is executed ( 4 cycle clock), then wavefront B is executed (another four cycle clock).
After wavefront B is executed (the total cycle clock is 8), the wavefront A will be executed again with another instruction.

The question is:

**How ALU execute another instruction if four ALU for each processing element is already used to execute another instruction??**

For Example:
In cycle 1, work item 0-15 begin to execute instruction "ADD". 
The first ALU in each processing element (total 16 PE in SIMD / compute unit) calculate "ADD" instruction.
It happens in cycle 2, 3, and 4 for a wavefront (now there are 4 ALU in each PE that keep busy to execute the "ADD" instruction)
In cycle 5, a quarter of wavefront 2 begin to execute instruction "SUBTRACT".
How ALU in processing element calculate the instruction since they are busy to calculate
"ADD" instruction from first wavefront (Remember that the execution for instruction "ADD" for a quarter of wavefront in first cycle is unfinished since it take 8 cycle clock)??

Update:
8 cycle clock means the latency of read after write

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_pipeline

Comment: Sorry, 8 cycle clock means the latency of read after write. I already read wikipedia and understand the concept but if one instruction takes eight cycle, how ALU execute instructions from second wavefront (cycle 5-8) if all ALUs in each processing element still execute instructions from first wavefront (cycle 0-4) that takes 8 cycle clock to complete??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated, it takes 4 clock cycles for a wavefront to be processed.  The results of that instruction get sent to the registers but, because of the read-after-write latency, these results will only be available after 8 clock cycles.  The important distinction here is that the ALUs finished their work in 4 cycles so they can go on processing other instructions.  The register memory takes 8 cycles to do its job, i.e. store the new data and make it visible again.

As a general note for all types of memory accesses, including registers: Memory accesses get handled differently to normal arithmetic, the ALUs can continue executing instructions that don't depend on the results of the memory access while waiting for the memory access to finish.

Comment: What kind of register takes four clock cycles to propagate the input to the output?

Comment: Apparently, AMDs.  This is my interpretation of section 7.6.1 of the AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing OpenCL Programming Guide revision 2.7 (November 2013).  Nvidia is similar according to section 9.2.6 of the CUDA 5.5 best practices guide.

Comment: Can ou quote it here? I can't access PDFs now.

Comment: Part 1 of 2: 7.6.1 Hiding ALU and Memory Latency
The read-after-write latency for most arithmetic operations (a floating-point add,
for example) is only eight cycles. For most AMD GPUs, each compute unit can
execute 16 VLIW instructions on each cycle. Each wavefront consists of 64 workitems;
each compute unit executes a quarter-wavefront on each cycle, and the
entire wavefront is executed in four consecutive cycles. Thus, to hide eight cycles
of latency, the program must schedule two wavefronts.

Comment: Part 2 of 2: The compute unit
executes the first wavefront on four consecutive cycles; it then immediately
switches and executes the other wavefront for four cycles. Eight cycles have
elapsed, and the ALU result from the first wavefront is ready, so the compute unit
can switch back to the first wavefront and continue execution. Compute units
running two wavefronts (128 threads) completely hide the ALU pipeline latency.

Comment: These two parts are the 1st paragraph of section 7.6.1 of the AMD OpenCL Programming Guide.